# PyTorch on Linux\ARM (BeagleBone Black or other)

Tags: raspberry-pi, arm, pytorch, nvidia, beagleboneblack

we're embarking on a project with Linux\ARM and Deep Learning. Currently prototyping with PyTorch on PC and looking for a target Linux\ARM platform which has good and straightforward support.

1. any recommendation on a supported Linux\ARM platform for TensorFlow or PyTorch would be much appreciated.
2. out current Linux\ARM reference device is BeagleBone Black. is there a supported, straightforward of installing TF\PyTorch on BBB?
3. same as above for OpenCV

Thanks!

FWIW, see logs of trying to install PyTorch and OpenCV on BBB with PIP. Looking for a way that will work out of the box, preferably on BBB but other Linux\ARM devices could work as well.

debian@beaglebone:~$ pip3 install torch==1.6.0 torchvision==0.7.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
Collecting torch==1.6.0
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.6.0 (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2)
No matching distribution found for torch==1.6.0

debian@beaglebone:~$ pip3 install cv2
Collecting cv2
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cv2 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for cv2